# Property does not exist on type 'Class' when using filter in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I am using `array.filter` in an Angular pipe, and I imported a class I have created:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import Product from '../models/Product';

@Pipe({
  name: 'products'
})
export class ProductsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(products: Product[], valueToSearch: string): any {
    return products.filter( product => product.name);
  }

}
```

For some reason, I am getting this error: `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Product'`, which is funny, because it absolutely does exist on type Product.

This is the second time it happens with filter, can anyone help?

The Model:

```
export default class Product {
    public constructor(
        ID: number,
        name: string,
        category: string,
        price: number,
        imageURL: string
    ) {};
}
```

***I managed to figure it out, my model did not have his properties as 'public' .***

Comment: Add code for '../models/Product';

Comment: Share your model

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out, my model did not have his properties as 'public'.
It now looks like this:

```
export default class Product {
    public constructor(
        public ID: number,
        public name: string,
        public category: string,
        public price: number,
        public imageURL: string
    ) {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is great you figured out the issue, another solution would be to use an interface instead. This would be appropriate as your class seems not to have any methods hence interface would be appropriate for typing

```typescript
export interface Product {
   ID: number,
   name: string,
   category: string,
   price: number,
   imageURL: string
}
```

and import it like `import { Product } from '..models/Product'`